# How to change firefox startpage from Ubuntu's to Firefox's?

Tags: firefox

Well, I installed Ubuntu GNOME Remix. Now I miss the "Restore Previous Session" button that Firefox start page has. How do I get it back?

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
about:home
```

in your URL bar is the page you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Try `about:home` in your address bar. You can set your start page any time under Preferences -> General tab.